# Python Scrapy does not crawl website

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy

I am new to python scrapy and trying to get through a small example, however I am having some problems! 
I am able to crawl the first given URL only, but I **am unable to crawl more than one page** or an entire website for that matter!

Please help me or give me some advice on how I can crawl an entire website or more pages in general...

The example I am doing is very simple...
My items.py

```
import scrapy
    class WikiItem(scrapy.Item):
        title = scrapy.Field()
```

my wikip.py (the spider)

```
import scrapy
from wiki.items import WikiItem

class CrawlSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "wikip"
    allowed_domains = ["en.wikipedia.org/wiki/"]
    start_urls = (
        'http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal:Arts',
    )

    def parse(self, response):
        for sel in response.xpath('/html'):
            item = WikiItem()
            item['title'] = sel.xpath('//h1[@id="firstHeading"]/text()').extract()
            yield item
```

When I run **scrapy crawl wikip -o data.csv** in the root project diretory the result is:

```
title

Portal:Arts
```

Can anyone give me insight as to why it is not following urls and crawling deeper?

I have checked some related SO questions but they have not helped to solve the issue

Comment: Where are you scraping more pages? You pull one xpath which you then pull an item from and that is it, what do you expect to happen?

Comment: You named your `scrapy.Spider` subclass `"CrawlSpider"`. I reckon you should have a look at subclassing built-in [`scrapy.CrawlSpider`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider) instead, and [define some rules](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawling-rules) to crawl further pages. You'll need to name your callbacks something different from "parse" (which should not be overriden in the general case). Check the [example spider in the docs](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#crawlspider-example).

Answer (score 1):

**scrapy.Spider** is the simplest spider. Change the name CrawlSpider, since **Crawl Spider** is one of the generic spiders of scrapy.

One of the below option can be used:

eg: 1. `class WikiSpider(scrapy.Spider)`

or 2. `class WikiSpider(CrawlSpider)`

If you are using first option you need to code the logic for following the links you need to follow on that webpage.

For second option you can do the below:

After the start urls you need to define the rule as below:

`rules = (
          Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portal:Arts\?.*?')), callback='parse_item', follow=True,),
    )`

Also please change the name of the function defined as "**parse**" if you use CrawlSpider. The Crawl Spider uses parse method to implement the logic. Thus, here you are trying to override the parse method and hence the crawl spider doesn't work.